# ProgressBar Overlay Or ProgressBar from Copy Functions

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

```
Function GetTotalBytesOfCopyDestination{ 

    param($destinationPath);
    $colItems = (Get-ChildItem $destinationPath | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
    return $colItems.sum;
}

Function GetBytesOfFile{

    param($sourcePath);
    return (Get-Item $sourcePath).length; 
}

Function GetPosition{

    param([double]$currentOfBytesSended)
    param([double]$countsOfBytesWillSend)
    $position = ($currentOfBytesSended / $countsOfBytesWillSend) * 100;

    #range 0 - 100
    #(15800 bytes / 1975633689 bytes)*100
    #

    return $position;
}

Function Copy-File {
    #.Synopsis
    # Copies all files and folders in $source folder to $destination folder, but with .copy inserted before the extension if the file already exists
    param($source,$Destination2)

    # create destination if it's not there ...
    mkdir $Destination2 -force -erroraction SilentlyContinue

    [double]$currentOfBytesSended = 0;

    [double]$countsOfBytesWillSend = 0;
    [double]$countsOfBytesWillSend = GetTotalBytesOfCopyDestination($source);

    $progressbar6.Maximum = 100;
    $progressbar6.Step = 1;

    foreach($original in ls $source -recurse) {
      $result = $original.FullName.Replace($source,$Destination2)
      while(test-path $result -type leaf){ $result = [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($result,"copy$([IO.Path]::GetExtension($result))") }

        [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()

        if($original.PSIsContainer) {
        mkdir $result -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
         } else {
        copy $original.FullName -destination $result

        [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()

            $currentCopyingFileSizeInBytes = 0;
            $currentCopyingFileSizeInBytes = GetBytesOfFile($original.FullName);

            $currentOfBytesSended = [double]$currentOfBytesSended + [double]$currentCopyingFileSizeInBytes;
            #$currentOfBytesSended += $currentCopyingFileSizeInBytes;


            $progressbar6.Value=GetPosition([double]$currentOfBytesSended, [double]$countsOfBytesWillSend);

            [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()

            #$progressbar6.PerformStep();
            $progressbar6.Refresh();
      }
    }
    }
```

what I'm trying to get is Copy-File Function ,copy files & directory from remote machine to local machine while moving progress bar depending on total amount to copy,and which are already copied and it define position for the progress bar and i get this error

```
ERROR: GetPosition : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'currentOfBytesSended'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]"
ERROR: to type "System.Double".
Assit App.pff (337): ERROR: At Line: 337 char: 35
ERROR: +                 $progressbar6.Value=GetPosition([double]$currentOfBytesSended, [double]$coun ...
ERROR: +                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [GetPosition], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,GetPosition
ERROR:
>> Script Ended
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Try to break up your questions into individual questions, rather than grouping many of them together. The format of this site is better suited to one question, one answer, unless maybe there is guidance that states otherwise.

## Excluding Folders

You can ignore folders by using the `Exclude` parameter on the `Get-ChildItem` command.

Imagine that you have a folder structure similar to the following:

`c:\gci
  |
  |\a
  |  \a.txt
  |\b
  |  \b.txt
  |\c
  |  \c.txt`

If you only want to get the contents of `c:\gci\a` and `c:\gci\c`, you can exclude `c:\gci\b` using the command:

`Get-ChildItem -Path c:\gci -Exclude b* -Recurse;`

Keep in mind that this will also exclude other items starting with "b" such as `c:\gci\bcd.txt`.

## Progress Bar

You can create a progress bar using the `Write-Progress` command. You will have to write your own, custom logic to determine what tasks to report progress on, and what the percentage of progress is. You can do this based on the number of bytes copied vs. the total number of bytes to be copied, the number of files copied vs. the total number of files, or some other sort of metric.

There's no simple answer to this one. You will have to perform the calculations yourself, and call `Write-Progress` at the appropriate times.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, i will try to edited one and use it, any idea why its not responding while copying?

Comment: @TiTu: If you're doing any type of GUI work, and you're running operations on the UI thread, then the UI will hang while the code is executing.

Comment: :i have change alot of things now :) still i get error ,please check the re-edited subject